# How many recessed lights should I install in my living room?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting, light

I've got a 18" x 12" living room that I want to install recessed lights into but I am stuck as to if I should install 6 or 8 lights (6 inch each). 6 already "looks" like there are a bunch of holes in the ceiling and I Just feel like 8 may be too crowed. but then again, what if 6 doesn't provide enough light? What do you guys think?

Comment: Think a lot about where the light is going to fall.  There's no point lighting up walls.  If you're going to do that, then do cove lighting instead.

Answer (score 2):

The questions you are asking are two fold.

1: How much light do I need to provide good visibility in this room - Lumens / Coverage.

2: Aesthetically what will this look like - good or awful ? Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

What is the layout of the six lights ? You did not mention - 3 and 3  along the long length or otherwise.

See the example below I think it will help you to decide. get a lamp of at least 800 lumens - you can get 75 watt equivalent for your recess assemblies which would be about 1000 lumens and that would make the area really bright. LEDs are pretty cheap and I would suggest you use them as well.

[image]

Comment: I was going to do two rows of three like you displayed above however, I had each can spaced 6 feet apart and 3 feet from the walls. would that be a bad idea? Admittedly I'm not very sure of what the ideal spacing should be. originally I was also thinking 65 watt equiv LED should I do 75 watt equiv then? Am I really pushing it with 6 and should be using 8 cans?

Comment: I am big on light so that on game night no one is left in the dark. I recommend the extra two cans, LED's are a must.  Then install a dimmer. When you want low ambient you can have it to snuggle on the couch.

Comment: IMHO 4.5 feet is a little tight for spacing. I have 4" cans installed with 600 lumen LEDs with 4 lights in a 15'x15' bedroom and it is plenty for ambient light. Using 6" lights you will get even more light and 6 should be plenty for ambient light. If you need more light for task lighting consider a tighter pattern. If the room is a kitchen or a workshop you may want more light but a living room or bedroom needs less.

Comment: @ArchonOSX you are correct we are expressing opinions on the numbers and spacing - as that is aesthetics. Aesthetically your 4 inch cans are probably more appealing for that space.However 6 inch cans do not give more light - they are just bigger cans. The bulb that is in those cans how many lumens they put out is what makes the difference in brightness. While it is true the bigger the can the more choices for higher lumen bulbs there are. And you are correct task lighting requires more luminosity - I have an area of a kitchen 10 feet long that has 4 six inch recessed lamps with 75W equivs.

Comment: hhmm. good advice guys. so i think I'll go with 75watt equivs but still uncertain about 6 or 8. im not even sure how 8 would fit in that space. there doesnt seem like enough space for say another row. how would more be added?

Comment: @John you are probably better off with just the 6 bulbs; adding another row  - you don't need another row to add 2 more bulbs - you could put them in the centers of the left quad and the right quad  (the quads share the same center lamps) but that center area would be bright. Of course you could move the outer two lights closer to the ends and still center the additional two with in the quads - really up to you as to what will look good.
Perhaps you could run a mock up and hang them to the ceiling and test for lighting..

Comment: ok. I settled on 6 cans but am still unsure of spacing. Because of where the beams lye in the ceiling, the cans will be laid out 4ft-5ft-5ft-4ft in the 18 foot direction. However, I am uncertain as to how far to spread the rows in the 12foot direction. I've come down to two options: Should I do 3ft-6ft-3ft? or should I do 3.5ft-5ft-3.5ft?

Comment: @John I would probably go with the [3/6/6/3] lengthwise, [3 / 6 / 3] width wise; these are the optimum spacing for lighting with 6 cans -  trying to spread the lighting out a bit for more even coverage - if you move too far - you might have 'dark' spots ... areas that are under-saturated with light .. so with your width the selection is obvious - but with your beams in the way on the lengthwise - you will need to choose what is possible with what is optimum. With [4ft-5ft-5ft-4ft] lengthwise , you have light at 4' and then at [2.5' < (midpoint ) > 2.5'] , [2.5' < (midpoint ) > 2.5'] then 4'.